i am trying to develop a user interface where i am facing problem to incorporate javascript with flask
In UI, there 2 buttons with different functionality, when clicked on buttons i want it to perform it's respective functionality i.e,

1st button : requests for answer given a question which is input.
2nd button: helps me to choose random question if user doesn't want
to give input.

As I click on these two buttons both are giving me answers which should not be the case, i want only the request for answer button to provide me answers.
app.py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = UserInput()
    # request_method = request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        connect = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        resp = requests.post(connect)
        url = resp.json()['URL']
        message = resp.json()['text']
        return render_template('home.html', title='home', form=form, url=url, 
        message=message)
        # return redirect('/home')
    return render_template('index.html', title='index', form=form)

forms.py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.fields.simple import TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class UserInput(FlaskForm):
    text = TextAreaField('Enter your Question ', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Request for the Answer')
    feedback = StringField('Feedback')
    randomisation = SubmitField('Choose a random question')

layout.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='style1.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask UI - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask UI</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action=" ">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.text.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.text(class="form-control form-control-lg",rows="5") }}
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group d-grid gap-2">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

home.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <div>
            {{ form.randomisation }}
        </div>
        <ul class = "label-for-list"> Files:
            <li class="list"><a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class ="second">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Answer: </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="12">{{ message }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback-button">
            {{ form.feedback.label(class="form-label") }}
            <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" id="thumbsup" title="thumbs-up" onclick="sendFeedback('up')">
            <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" id="thumbsdown" title="thumbs-down" onclick="sendFeedback('down')">
        </div>
        <script>
            function sendFeedback(action) {
            const thumbsUp = document.getElementById('thumbsup');
            const thumbsDown = document.getElementById('thumbsdown');

            if (action === 'up') {
            // change the colour when a up button is clicked
               thumbsUp.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
               thumbsDown.style.backgroundColor = '';
               console.log('positive')

            } if (action === 'down') {
               // change the colour when a down button is clicked
                thumbsDown.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                thumbsUp.style.backgroundColor = '';
                console.log('Negative')
              }
            }
        </script>
{% endblock content %}

index.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}

api.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from wonderwords import RandomSentence
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def func():
    print(request.method)
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        response = "This is just GET request and API is up and running"
        return jsonify({'response': response})

    elif(request.method == 'POST'):
        data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
        url = f"https:\\SourceDir\\file{random.randint(0,10)}.pdf"
        s = RandomSentence()
        # d = {"text":data.strip('\"'),'URL':url}
        d = {"text": s.sentence(), "URL": url}
        return d

